SQL Server Change Tracking issue
Anyone else experienced this issue with SQL Server Change Tracking (CT)?
We are running SQL Server 2019 Standard Edition (version 15.0.4410.1) in production. We have 351 databases across the estate all using Change Tracking against 267 tables in each database.
For some unknown reason we consistently have the same 2 tables in just 2 databases where the CT row count stats become inaccurate causing the optimizer to generate sub-optimal plans leading to long running queries and timeouts. For example, one of the live tables has around 60K rows but it's CT side table stats report 22M rows.
The auto-clean up has a retention period of 4 days and judging by the logs its running successfully for these 2 tables in question. There's no sign of a problem with this process, it is purging rows.
Manually refreshing the stats on the tables and their side tables does not correct the row counts. The only remedy we have found to date is to disable and re-enable CT on the tables. This corrects the row counts allowing the optimizer to generate a faster performing plan and fixes the timeouts. But after a few days the issue re-occurs and the row count stats are once again inaccurate.

"Manually refreshing the stats on the tables and their side tables does not correct the row counts." can you show that script? Also can you share the execution plan you're having difficulty with via https://pastetheplan.com

What's different between those databases vs the others? Maybe start by verifying the database settings.

Have you tried running DBCC UPDATEUSAGE?
DBCC UPDATEUSAGE (DBName,'TableNameGoesHere') WITH COUNT_ROWS;

This command will correct the row count for the given table. Documentation
